# syntax error with IF statement in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following logic in my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
Test:
  stage: unit-test
  environment:
    name: development
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64
  script:
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
    - apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
    - apt-get install nodejs
    - npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
    - cd ./tests
    - dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\TestResults\test-results.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./TestResults/test-results.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./TestResults/test-results.xml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE == "/-dev$/"'
  tags:
    - mac-pipelines
```

I'm getting a syntax error:

```
jobs:test:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried the following changes - all failed.  :)

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE = /-dev$/

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE = /-dev$/'


  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE == /-dev$/'
```

I'm presently googling other IF examples... but if you can point out my mistake, i'd appreciate the help.

EDIT 1

Updated the code to use this:

```
 - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-dev$/'
```

although the syntax error is gone, the pipeline does the opposite of what I want.  When i commit a change with the commit message "Testing -dev", I expect all jobs that have the rule

rules:
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE == /-dev$/'

to run, and any job that has:

rules:
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-dev$/'

to be skipped.
But it's doing the opposite.

Comment: Relevant documentation link, specifically towards the bottom of this "Common clauses" section: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules

Comment: cool @ahogen.  I think i found the smoking gun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the regex matching operator (`=~`) for re expressions

```yaml
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-dev$/'
```

If you want to do a negative match against the pattern, use `!~`.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @dot can you double check you edit for accuracy? I'm not sure it makes much sense to me. Perhaps consider asking a separate question if your original question is now answered.

Comment: Yeah I think I misunderstood your answer.  it's good.  I've accepted the answer.

Comment: Use `=~` to check if it **matches** a **pattern** -- use `!~` to check if it **does not match** a **pattern**. Use `==` to check if it **matches** a **string**. Use `!=` to check if it **does not match** a **string**.

Comment: yeah :). I get it now.  Sorry for the noise..  I just misread your answer the first time, but rereading your answer and the article reference above helped.  Thank you!